# Building Solana from Source results in error: expected item, found `..` --> frozen-abi/macro/build.rs:1:1

Tags: wsl, windows, solana-cli, solana-test-validator

When running `./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .` from the instructions in the Solana docs (https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#build-from-source) I am seeing

```
error: expected item, found '..'
 --> frozen-abi/macro/build.rs:1:1
  |
1 | ../build.rs
  | ^^ expected item

error: expected item, found '..'
 --> sdk/build.rs:1:1
  |
1 | ../frozen-abi/build.rs
  | ^^ expected item

error: expected item, found '..'
 --> program-runtime/build.rs:1:1
  |
1 | ../frozen-abi/build.rs
  | ^^ expected item

error: expected item, found '..'
 --> sdk/program/build.rs:1:1
  |
1 | ../../frozen-abi/build.rs
  | ^^ expected item

error: could not compile 'solana-program-runtime' due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

I have to build Solana from source because when I installed Solana through the command prompt from the Windows instructions in the docs, running `solana-test-validator` results in `ERROR solana_perf] Incompatible CPU detected: missing AVX2 support. Please build from source on the target`

I am on Windows 10 using WSL: Ubuntu-18.04.

Would switching to a new Macbook help?

Comment: What version of the CLI are you trying to run?

Comment: @JacobCreech I was using the main branch from the solana-labs repo, but after switching to v1.9.29 I no longer am having these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I had to clone the repo instead of downloading the Source Code zip file. https://forums.solana.com/t/solana-test-validator-error-missing-avx2/3272/10

Comment: elaborating the contents of the link here would improve the quality of this answer